# 2Checkout + Angular > Inline Checkout > redirects to the full checkout page

Tags: angularjs, 2checkout

**Problem**

I'm following the [2Checkout docs for setting up the Inline Checkout](https://www.2checkout.com/documentation/checkout/inline-checkout). I have not been able to get the iframe popup to appear.  No matter what I try it redirects to the full checkout experience.

**Failed Troubleshooting**

I was unable to find anything that directly addressed my issue via Google or on Stackoverflow.  The only mention of it seems to be from the docs themselves.  At the bottom of the docs it suggests trying the following if you have this issue:

> Clear your browser’s cache and cookies, close all open instances of your browser, then recommence testing.

- Cleared cache and cookies between each try.
- The above + closed the browser each time.
- The above + Chrome's Incognito

> Review your page to ensure that the mandatory JavaScript code has been properly implemented.

I can see via Chrome's dev tools `Network` tab that the JS from the docs (shown below) is loaded on the page without issue. Also, when I navigate to it directly I do see the minified JS.

```
<script src="https://www.2checkout.com/static/checkout/javascript/direct.min.js"></script>
```

> Ensure that you are using the Hosted Checkout parameter set to pass in sale details.

- I tried using the exact code from the example in the docs, which it says has all the requirements.
- The above + my sandbox account number as the only change.
- The above + a few other value changes and new fields, which is closer to what I really want...

*(pointing at the sandbox per the docs)*

```
<form action="https://sandbox.2checkout.com/checkout/purchase" method="post">
  <input name="sid" value="901341903" />
  <input name="mode" value="2CO" />
  <input name="li_0_tangible" value="N" />
  <input name="li_0_type" value="product" />
  <input name="li_0_name" value="Website" />
  <input name="li_0_price" value="5" />
  <input name="li_0_recurrence" value="1 Month" />
  <input name="card_holder_name" value="Joe Flagster" />
  <input name="street_address" value="123 Main Street" />
  <input name="street_address2" value="" />
  <input name="city" value="Townsville" />
  <input name="state" value="OH" />
  <input name="zip" value="43206" />
  <input name="country" value="USA" />
  <input name="email" value="example@2co.com" />
  <input name="phone" value="614-921-2450" />
  <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Checkout" />
</form>
```

**Potentially Relevant Info**

- According to my sandbox account I am `Approved to Sell`, but `Not Eligible for Payments`
- I am developing on a locally hosted virtual dedicated server.  I have
  it setup to show my domain as `https://www.example.com:3000` instead
  of `localhost:3000`.
- My project is built with Angular 1.6.x

Any assistance, experience, insight, etc. with this will be greatly appreciated!

---

### UPDATE 3/14/2017

Screenshot of my code (I added `li_0_duration`):
[image: Form]

Screenshots of the standard cart after the undesired redirect:
[image: Review Cart][image: Billing Information][image: Payment Method]

The only empty required fields are in the `Payment Methods` section, but that's data the user is supposed to submit in the `iframe` popup, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Problem Summary**

I downloaded the unminified version of the JS...
https://www.2checkout.com/static/checkout/javascript/direct.js

...and hosted it locally so that I could troubleshoot.  I discovered that `onready` was getting triggered before the DOM is fully ready.  This caused the error.

It seems the 2Checkout script was tricked by how the Angular framework loads and manages views.  The 2Checkout script did not find and analyze the form element correctly because the form element wasn't in the DOM when the 2Checkout script was loaded.  Among other things the 2Checkout script ought to inject a hidden input named `tco_use_inline` into the form (determined by the value of the form's `action` attribute), but it wasn't doing that for me.

**Angular Solution**

I created a temporary patch.  Add this to the controller of the template the form is in...

```
$scope.$watch("ready", function() {
  var s = document.createElement("script");
  s.src = 'https://www.2checkout.com/static/checkout/javascript/direct.min.js';
  document.body.append(s);
});
```

...and then add `ng-init="ready"` to the form.

```
<form ng-init="ready" action="..." method="...">
  ...
</form>
```

Once the form is loaded in the DOM it will declare `ready`, which triggers the `$watch` in the controller, which will dynamically inject the 2Checkout script.  Thus, everything gets loaded in the correct order.

Answer (score 0):

Anytime you're using inline and it redirects to standard checkout instead,  you're missing a parameter or the values input by the user are causing a problem.

Once you hit the standard checkout page, check the form fields on each drop down slider, one of the required fields should appear empty and show a *required* message. That parameter is your problematic parameter, since we're sending the buyer to the standard checkout routine to re-collect the information once more.

Only additional param you need to include with your above html snippet is li_0_duration. Set your value (e.g. 1 year) and you should be all set, the iframe should show as long as you're including the line of javascript, which it sounds like you already have covered.

https://www.2checkout.com/documentation/checkout/parameters for further documentation around the parameter set.

Comment: There are no empty required fields or any error messages other than the missing credit card data, which is empty by design because the user is supposed to supply it, right?

Comment: I updated my question with screenshots. Can you spot whatever I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I found the problem. The 2Checkout script was loading before the `<form>` was in the DOM.  I have a workaround (accepted answer). Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have all the **mandatory** are parameters present

Check the **name** attribute of the parameters, make sure the spelling is correct